# Is there a way to take a screenshot in codenameone (especially for Android)?

Tags: java, codenameone, screenshot

I tried to take a Screenshot every second, to find out, if the user is in a menu of another app. I found a function in Display named `capturePhoto(...)` but it's a void function. I also tried it with Robot, but it isn't supported.

I googled it, but only found text not code to use.

The function I found: `Display.getInstance().capturePhoto(null);`

I don't know what goes there instead of null

Comment: I suppose that take a screenshot every second is cpu-intensive...

Comment: @FrancescoGalgani answer is correct but isn't what `Robot` would do and won't capture the screen when your app isn't in focus. That would be a serious security vulnerability in the OS and all native OS's block this by default. It's actually really hard to do that even in Android... FYI `capturePhoto` uses the device camera

Answer (score 2):

To take a screenshot in Codename One, you can use the following static method:

```
    /**
     * Returns a screenshot of the currently displayed Form, or null if no form
     * is shown
     *
     * @return
     */
    public static Image getScreenshot() {
        Form form = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        if (form != null) {
            Image screenshot = Image.createImage(form.getWidth(), form.getHeight());
            form.paintComponent(screenshot.getGraphics(), true);
            return screenshot;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

It works in all the platforms supported by Codename One, not only on Android.

Comment: This would work perfectly, if i wanted to take a Screenshot in my own App, but sadly, I need to take the Screenshot outside of my App in another App. I want to take a Screenshot, to find out if there is a specific menu opened in the other App. Your function only takes a Screenshot of my app and not a Screenshot of the other App.

Comment: It’s impossible to take a screenshot of another app, as Shai commented. Maybe there are other better solutions for your problem that don’t use screenshots.

Comment: I thought there would be a solution, because there are video record Apps, who record the screen. Thank you i will try something else.